# Why are interfaces turning into abstract classes c#

Tags: c#, interface

I'm honestly looking for good examples here of reasons to use interfaces over abstract. And the main reason I can see is they are unopinionated public blueprints for classes to follow. But with them adding default implementations thats no longer true. Its becoming more and more difficult to distinguish interfaces from abstract classes. Genuinely whats the point in using an interface over an abstract class in c# 11. Its just a slower abstract class.

Comment: Try writing a class that needs to implement two or more abstract base classes, and you'll be in a world of pain. Also, what do you mean by "slower"?

Comment: Interfaces becoming more powerful is a good thing, because they're more flexible (multiple implementation, variance). If anything you should always be looking for reasons to have an abstract class rather than an interface, instead of the other way around...

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, like C++. You cannot inherit more than one abstract class, but you can inherit multiple interfaces. Although abstract classes can contain protected constructors, cause is indeed a piece of object. Interfaces shouldn't be seen as a piece of object, but extensions we can add to them.  Example the IDisposable interface, it's not a inherited behavior, you just added the abilliy of the object free umanaged resources

Comment: I get the multiple inheritance point. Is that really the only positive point? Inheriting from multiple interfaces still has to be inherited from a single interface if you expect to be able to mock that class in your codebase later. 

Interfaces do a lookup for class methods before invoking them. They will always be slower than an abstract invoke

Comment: "Inheriting from multiple interfaces still has to be inherited from a single interface if you expect to be able to mock that class in your codebase later." Only if you need to mock all the interfaces it supports, in the same place. If you're only *using* one of those interfaces in the calling code, it's fine to just mock that.

Comment: "Interfaces do a lookup for class methods before invoking them". So do virtual methods. Calling an abstract member requires an indirect call, same with an interface. They're technically using identical code.

Comment: "Interfaces do a lookup for class methods before invoking them". So do virtual methods. Calling an abstract member requires an indirect call, same with an interface. They're technically using identical code.


I've always heard interfaces perform slower. But Ive never really tested it myself to see the difference. I assume it was fairly negligible, But could add up in super intensive tasks.

Comment: Could be based on some very deep implementation detail within the runtime, but would need a detailed analysis. If performance is _that_ crucial, avoid using virtual methods at all.

Comment: If performance is not a factor then id ask the reverse question. Why use abstract over interfaces? I always though of interfaces as blueprints for classes to follow. A contract that a class that inherits from them must follow, Completely unopinionated. And an abstract class as very similar but with the ability to be opinionated in the approach derived classes take in implementation. But with default implementations the lines feel very blurred.

Comment: "Why use abstract over interfaces?" To provide as much common implementation as possible, basically - and that can include state with abstract classes, but it can't for interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I find abstract classes and interfaces are too similar. I prefer using abstract classes, as its methods can be defined, until and unless there's the concept of multiple inheritance used.

As with case of abstract classes, we can't inherit from multiple abstract classes, whereas with interfaces, you could inherit as many interfaces you wish.

I'll let you understand this through a patch of code.

```cs
interface IFirstInterface
    {
        void myMethod();
    }
    interface ISecondInterface
    {
        void myOtherMethod();
    }
    class Democlass : IFirstInterface, ISecondInterface
    {
        public void myMethod()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Some text..");
        }
        public void myOtherMethod()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Some other text..");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Democlass myObj = new Democlass();
            myObj.myMethod();
            myObj.myOtherMethod();
        }
    }
```

Lemme know if you find this unclear.

Comment: This does seem to be the answer. I thought there might be more to it. The problem with this is that when youre trying to get everything behind an interface for unit testing, You still have to put "DemoClass" behind a single interface. You also cant DI a class with two interfaces ("AddSingleton<IFirstInterface, DemoClass>") which would mean you would still create a single interface that inherits from all other interfaces for democlass.